# Efficiently sample a single row of an array at random

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, r, rcpp

I have the following C++ code snippet that randomly samples a single row in an array called `pop` with `num_specs` columns and `perms` rows. In addition, `K` = 1. The triply-nested `for` loop uses a pointer for referencing.

Some of the below syntax (such as `IntegerVector`) is from Rcpp, an R package to integrate C++ code with R code.

```c++
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppProgress)]]
#define ARMA_DONT_PRINT_OPENMP_WARNING
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
#include <set>
using namespace Rcpp;

int sample_one(int n) {
  return n * unif_rand();
} 

int sample_n_distinct(const IntegerVector& x, 
                      int k,
                      const int * pop_ptr) {

IntegerVector ind_index = RcppArmadillo::sample(x, k, false);
std::set<int> distinct_container;

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    distinct_container.insert(pop_ptr[ind_index[i]]);
}

return distinct_container.size();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::Cube<int> accumulate(const arma::Cube<int>& pop,
                     const IntegerVector& specs,
                     int perms,
                     int K) {

int num_specs = specs.size();
arma::Cube<int> res(perms, num_specs, K);

IntegerVector specs_C = specs - 1;
const int * pop_ptr;
int i, j, k;

for (i = 0; i < K; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k < num_specs; k++) {
        for (j = 0; j < perms; j++) {
            pop_ptr = &(pop(sample_one(perms), 0, sample_one(K)));
            res(j, k, i) = sample_n_distinct(specs_C, k + 1, pop_ptr);
        }
    }
}
return res;
}
```

While loops in compiled languages aren't bad, it is possible to write slow code.

I'm not a native C++ programmer, so I don't know all the tricks of the trade.

Is there a way to reduce the number of levels in the triply-nested `for` loop above, possibly by employing modular arithmetic in order to see a gain in speed for large input values?

The R code is below:

```r
## Set up container to hold the identity of each individual from each permutation ##
num.specs <- N

## Create an ID for each tag ##
tags <- 1:h

## Assign individuals (N) ##
specs <- 1:num.specs

## Generate permutations. Assume each permutation has N individuals, and sample those 
# individuals' tags from the probabilities ##
  gen.perms <- function() {
      sample(tags, size = num.specs, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
  }

  pop <- array(dim = c(perms, num.specs, K))

  for (i in 1:K) {
    pop[,, i] <- replicate(perms, gen.perms())
  }

## Perform accumulation ##
HAC.mat <- accumulate(pop, specs, perms, K)

## Example
K <- 1
N <- 100
h <- 5
probs <- rep(1/h, h)
perms <- 100
```

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about [what your code does](//codereview.meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226) and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The current title states your concerns about the code; it needs an [edit] to simply *state the task*; see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks! I've added further detail to the title and post, which I hope is sufficient. Could you take a look?

Comment: @JarrettPhillips, let me add my two cents. The first problem I see is the absence of purpose: it should be clear why the code does what it does. Second: where does the array come from? What those functions are? Ideally code in question should be compilable and runnable, and output correct result. I know it is not always possible to do that, but at this stage it is hard to give effective review.

Comment: @TobySpeight Understandable. I've now added the full code, which is written with the purpose of being integrated with R via the Rcpp package. I've also changed the title to be a bit more informative.

Comment: @JarrettPhillips can you add R code example how you use this function? so we can run and test it

Comment: @TobySpeight I've now added the full code with a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: That's looking quite a bit better now (and I've withdrawn my close-vote).  You could improve the title a bit: focus on the high-level goal, rather than the mechanism.  The title really should go with the *motivation* part of the explanation (which is still very thin), rather than *mechanism* - see [ask] and the "How to get the best value" link from my first comment.  With that fixed up, you'll be good to go!  I hope you get some helpful answers; unfortunately, I've never used R, so that part is beyond my capabilities, but I might be able to look at the C++ now you've explained the purpose.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks. I've made some edits. Hopefully things are clarified for you and/or others to contribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only comment on the C++ code, as I've never used R nor Rcpp.

For an ignorant reader such as myself, it would have helped to omit the `using namespace Rcpp;`, so that I could see which names come from that library (I did quite a bit of external reading to even understand the code).

Assuming I'm right that `sample()` returns an array of length `k`, then we can use range-based `for` to iterate through its values (since `IntegerVector` has suitable `begin()` and `end()`):

```
// sample k values from x, without replacement
const Rcpp::IntegerVector ind_index = Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(x, k, false);

// how many different values do they index in pop_ptr?
std::set<int> distinct_container;
for (int i: ind_index) {
    distinct_container.insert(pop_ptr[i]);
}
```

In `accumulate()` (which name I dislike, because it sounds like `std::accumulate()`), we can reduce the scope of `i`, `j`, `k` and `pop_ptr` quite simply:

```
for (int i = 0; i < K; ++i) {
    for (int k = 0;  k < num_specs;  ++k) {
        for (int j = 0;  j < perms;  ++j) {
            const int *const pop_ptr = &(pop(sample_one(perms), 0, sample_one(K)));
            res(j, k, i) = sample_n_distinct(specs_C, k + 1, pop_ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I'd be inclined to show that the creation of `specs_C` is more than just a conversion from `specs - 1` - that's actually a constructor argument specifying the length of the new vector:

```
IntegerVector specs_C(specs - 1);
```

I don't see any code that ever modifies this vector; if it's supposed to remain full of zeros, then it can be declared `const`.

---

With those changes, and an automated re-indent, we get something like this for those two functions (I've compiled, but not tested this):

```
int sample_one(int n)
{
    return n * R::unif_rand();
}

int sample_n_distinct(const Rcpp::IntegerVector& x,
                      int k,
                      const int * pop_ptr)
{
    // sample k values from x, without replacement
    const auto ind_index = Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(x, k, false);

    // how many different values do they index in pop_ptr?
    std::set<int> distinct_container;
    for (int i: ind_index) {
        distinct_container.insert(pop_ptr[i]);
    }

    return distinct_container.size();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::Cube<int> accumulate(const arma::Cube<int>& pop,
                           const Rcpp::IntegerVector& specs,
                           int perms,
                           int K)
{
    auto const num_specs = specs.size();
    arma::Cube<int> res(perms, num_specs, K);

    Rcpp::IntegerVector specs_C(specs - 1);

    for (int i = 0;  i < K;  ++i) {
        for (int k = 0;  k < num_specs; ++k) {
            for (int j = 0;  j < perms; ++j) {
                const auto& sampled = pop(sample_one(perms), 0, sample_one(K));
                res(j, k, i) = sample_n_distinct(specs_C, k + 1, &sampled);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

---

Sadly, I don't have the domain knowledge to suggest more meaningful improvements other than these fairly mechanical changes that improve readability.

In particular, I don't understand why we have to pass `specs_C` to `accumulate()` instead of sampling directly from `pop_ptr`.

I'm also very wary of taking the address of the element returned by `pop()` - that seems to assume a memory layout that could vary between platforms, for instance.  I'd expect to use one of the [subcube view](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#subcube) operations to construct the population:

```
int sample_n_distinct(const Rcpp::IntegerVector& population, int k)
{
    // sample k values from population, without replacement
    const auto sampled = Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(population, k, false);

    // how many different values do have?
    std::set<int> distinct(sampled.begin(), sampled.end());

    return distinct.size();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::Cube<int> accumulate(const arma::Cube<int>& pop,
                           const Rcpp::IntegerVector& specs,
                           int perms,
                           int K)
{
    auto const num_specs = specs.size();
    arma::Cube<int> res(perms, num_specs, K);

    for (int i = 0;  i < K;  ++i) {
        for (int k = 0;  k < num_specs; ++k) {
            for (int j = 0;  j < perms; ++j) {
                const auto& sampled = pop.tube(sample_one(perms), sample_one(K));
                const auto sampled_vector
                    = Rcpp::IntegerVector(sampled.begin(), sampled.end());
                res(j, k, i) = sample_n_distinct(sampled_vector, k + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

I may be wrong on exactly what subcube view is required, so `pop.tube()` may need to be a different call, but you get the idea.  See how much simpler life is when you can use iterators instead of grubbing around with pointers?

Comment: Well, it's syntactically correct; I don't have the unit tests to actually *prove* it gives the right results, but presumably you do, and can trivially swap implementations and test them.

Comment: Yes, I'll give it a run and let you know! I greatly appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Your first implementation works nicely! For your second implementation, I would need to instal C++11

Comment: Ah - the question didn't mention that you were stuck with ancient version of C++!

Comment: Yes - I should have mentioned that. Do you think there will be a performance gain from the usage of **auto**, seeing that variable type is inferred only at compile time? I've heard different stories pertaining to this aspect.

Comment: No runtime difference - you can confirm that by inspecting the generated code (which will probably be identical).  It mainly saves programmer (and reviewer) time.